# Use Tinc to route to a server

Tags: linux, route, tinc

I have tinc up and running. What I want to achieve is in the picture:
[Network schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnfBN.png)

I want to be able to reach the server X behind Tinc B via Tinc A. I can ping the Tinc servers and even ping the local (nic) address of B from A. But I can't reach X. I can't install Tinc on that server X because it is not compatible (the application crashes).

I suppose it has to do with routes I need to add, but I don't know where (on A or B or both) and what I need to set for the routes.
I'm flexible when it comes to the IP addresses that I should use so I didn't give my current setting to avoid confusion if I made it wrong already.

Can this be done with tinc?

Comment: Yes you can set this up. Check the guide. https://wikileaks.org/ciav7p1/cms/page_13763718.html

Comment: I basically set it up that way. But looking at it again the magic word in the configuration file of host 2 might be "router".  I'll give it a try tonight.

Comment: So I tried it. `Mode = router` is the default setting, so without knowing I specified it already. I want to reach a server X behind the _tinc_ B from A. Network address of X is 192.168.178.10, of B 192.168.178.20, the tinc address of B is 10.0.0.2, the tinc address of A is 10.0.0.1. Pinging between the two is no issue.